# Number of ways to put hat(s) in $5$ boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

> If their are two kinds of hats , red and blue and at least $5$ of each kind, in
>   how many ways can the hats be put in each in each of the $5$ different boxes.

I assumed that their are $10$ hats $5$ red and blue each.

so I counted as $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ red hats or/and $1,2,3,4,5,6$

blue hats can be put in one box,
as at least one hat should be in a box,

hence subsequently I calculated

$6\times 5+5\times 4+4\times 3+3\times 2+2\times 1=70$ ways

But the answer given in book is $35$ ways.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

**EDIT**: **The Book's solution** given is as follows.

> > The significance of at least $5$ hats of each kind is that while putting a hat
> >      in each box we have the option of either putting a red hat or a blue hat. 
> >     (If this was not given, there would have been an uncertainty in the no of 
> >     possibilities of putting a hat in a box.) Thus, in this question, for every 
> >     task of putting a hat in a box, we have the possibility of either putting a 
> >     red hat or a blue hat. The solution can then be looked at as: there are $5$
> >      tasks each of which can be done in $2$ ways. Through the MNP rule, we 
> >     have the total no of ways = $2^{5}$.

Comment: This needs some more information. You say there are at least 5 of each color hat, but that means there could be 50, or 500, as well.

Comment: It is the way given in book , Though I assume author meant 5 red and 5 blue hats.

Comment: Apparently, there was a great deal of missing context at the beginning.  The question should read "If we have five distinct boxes, and we wish to place exactly one hat in each box, and the hats available are red and blue but otherwise indistinct, and there are plenty of each color hat available, how many ways can this be accomplished?"  The way you phrased the question above makes it unclear how many boxes exist (5? 50? 1000? unlimited?), how many hats can fit in each box (1? 5? 1000? unlimited?), and whether or not the boxes are distinct.

Comment: Also, for the record, $35$ is not the answer the book gave, being $2^5=32$

Comment: The book's solution is short and simple; any fundamentally different solutions will just be unnecessarily complicated. So I'd suggest that instead of looking for different solutions, you should indicate what part of the book's solution you don't understand, so that it can be explained.

Comment: As I said earlier , the question was given in the book as I posted here , I didn't phrase the question,If the question is incorrect then can u elaborate it in the answer.